# Markers display with leaflet and javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, php

I have a problem displaying data relating to schools on a div 'info' when click the marker with leaflet and javascript:

here's the error:

Uncaught TypeError: layer.setStyle is not a function

Comment: You have two `layer.setStyle()` calls. Which one of them is failing? Add breakpoints and inspect the value of `layer` when it fails.

Comment: thank you, I solved the problem,here is the code that works:

Comment: @user28253 If you solved your problem can answer your question, just submit the answer and mark as answered. If you have another question please open another question, code in the comments is hard to read :(